# Magento 2 - eshop | Technologies that should be used

Tags: magento2, php, varnish

I recently assigned the implementation of my eshop to an agency, using magento 2. What I would like to ask, is what should I have in mind, in order to be sure the latest technologies are implemented given that my experience is minimal to say the least.

The eshop will host between 10000 to 15000 products

From what I know some key factors are:

the PHP version, to my best knowledge must be 7 and above

For the frontend CSS3 and HTML 5 should be used

Varnish Cache should be enabled

What else should I ask to be implemented considering this is 12000 dollars investment.

Some server recommended specs will be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: All  can be ready approximately  $8000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following specs are entirely from my experience implementing a project with similar number of SKUs:

- 8 core CPU
- 32 GB RAM
- SSD (disk size doesn't matter)

Performance wise, you should literally not bother with anything else until:

- The server is configured to fully utilize the provided 32 GB RAM (or more RAM that you'll have) for PHP-FPM opcode cache, MySQL buffers, etc.
- You have implemented Varnish cache. Until you have it working and configured, Magento 2 will be unbearably slow with any number of products.

For a full stack of technologies that can power up Magento 2, have a look at [Citrus Stack](https://www.getpagespeed.com/citrus-stack).

Answer (score 3):

**Basic Features Required :**

An eShop with **10000-15000 products** and latest technologies
   inbuilt like

- **Custom Front end and User Interface  Design**
- **PHP7 / MYSQL 5.6** / Apache 2.4
- HTML5 / CSS3 Using **LESS CSS Preprocessor**   / Bootstrap /
- Mobile-Tablet Optimized / Varnish Cache / NGNIX Compression Enabled /
- **SSD Enabled Server** / Shared SSL /
- **WordPress Blog**
- Live Chat With Customer Integration /
- **Admin/Dashboard** Management Training.

**Minimum Server Requirements** :

- PHP7 / MYSQL 5.6
- SSD Storage / Shared SSL
- **12 Core Server**
- **64 GB RAM Server**
- Brute Force Defense / Virus    Scanning
- Basic CDN
- **HTTP2 Ready**
- **SSH Access**
- cPanel Control
- GZIp Compression
- Physical Memory atleast 2GB
- Virtual Memory 8GB
- Multi Databases and Websites

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you mean by "Shared SSL"? :)

Comment: SSL (secure socket layers) encrypts information as it is transferred across the internet.  ... A Shared SSL certificate generated for the hostname of the server and Dedicated SSL certificate is generated for your domain name. Shared SSL can be used Without dedicated IP. So if you don't have dedicated IP than you can use Shared SSL